# Is it possible to catch a fetch request sent by a internal libary function that returns void?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, intercom

For context, I'm using the react-use-intercom library function `startTour(tourId: number) => void` that returns void regardless if the tourId is valid or not. In the code there's no way of checking the response status code like a typical fetch request, but in the network console, you can see that a fetch request was sent with the payload/response. Is it possible to catch that in the code still?

In the code, I only call two functions that both return void:

```
  const handleWhatsNewButtonClick = (): void => {
    boot();
    startTour(123456);
  };
```

The intercom pacakge reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-intercom

[network console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR2Jz.png)

Comment: You could probably monkey patch fetch, but no way out of the box to do hat you want. So intercom does not have anything to say it is invalid? Seems like that should be a feature request. lol

Comment: @epascarello Really a bug report if you ask me. But it's not the fault of the `react-use-intercom` package, it's really the [intercom api itself](https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/intercom-javascript) that has this restriction.

Comment: Right, I think they made it like that to make it customer friendly? It's easy to see it on the UI side cause the tour just won't start, but it's a hard for a dev to actually debug for it in the code.